# Oracle SQL Developer: Unable to find a JVM

Tags: java, oracle-sqldeveloper

I'm trying to open Oracle SQL Developer on my Windows7 64-bit.

When I tried to open SQL Developer it asked for java.exe path and I gave C:\Java\jdk1.6.0_34\jre\bin\java.exe

I got an error from Oracle SQL Developer saying: Unable to find a Java Virtual Machine. To point to a location of a JVM. Please refer to oracle9i jdeveloper install guide (jdev install.html)

[image]

[image]

Any clue on how to fix this?

**Another Solution:**

This worked for me several times. Install JDK7 and point to location of jdk7\jre\bin\java.exe

Answer (score 62, accepted):

Probably this is you are looking for (from [this](http://www.mkyong.com/oracle/oracle-sql-developer-unable-to-find-java-virtual-machine/) post):

> Oracle SQL developer is NOT support on 64 bits JDK. To solve it,
> install a 32 bits / x86 JDK and update your SQL developer config file,
> so that it points to the 32 bits JDK.
>
> Fix it! Edit the “sqldeveloper.conf“, which can be found under
> “{ORACLE_HOME}\sqldeveloper\sqldeveloper\bin\sqldeveloper.conf“, make
> sure “SetJavaHome” is point to your 32 bits JDK.

**Update**:
Based on @FGreg answer below, in the Sql Developer version 4.XXX you can do it in user-specific config file:

- Go to Properties -> Help -> About
- Add / Change ***SetJavaHome*** to your path (for example - C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.7.0_03) - this will override the setting in sqldeveloper.conf

**Update 2**: Based on @krm answer below, if your SQL Developer and JDK "bits" versions are not same, you can try to set the value of **SetJavaHome** property in product.conf

> ***SetJavaHome C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_80***
>
> The product.conf file is in my case located in the following directory:
>
> *C:\Users\username\AppData\Roaming\sqldeveloper\1.0.0.0.0*

Comment: Glad to be helpfull. Enjoy.

Comment: I downloaded win64_11gR2_client for 64-bit windows. On installing it, it created a directory: c:\Oracle11gClientApp\neal.walters\product\11.2.0\client_1\jdk\jre - so wouldn't it be smart enough to put the 32-bit version of the Java JDK here if that's what it wanted?

Comment: There is already a 64-bit version of SQL Developer which requires a 64-bit JDK to run. When I tried to run such version using a 32-bit JDK, then I could not start it. See my full answer for details.

Comment: @krm - updated the answer, thanks for valuable update :)

Comment: In my case, there were many sqldeveloper.conf files on my PC, but the one that I needed was the one most recently modified:
"C:\Oracle\Product\11.2.0\Client_32\sqldeveloper\sqldeveloper\bin\sqldeveloper.conf"

Answer (score 12):

I just installed SQL Developer 4.0.0.13 and the `SetJavaHome` can now be overridden by a user-specific configuration file (not sure if this is new to 4.0.0.13 or not).

The location of this user-specific configuration file can be seen in the `user.conf` property under 'Help -> About' on the 'Properties' tab. For example, mine was set to:

```
C:\Users\username\AppData\Roaming\sqldeveloper\1.0.0.0.0\product.conf
```

On Windows 7.

The first section of this file is used to set the JDK that SQLDeveloper should use:

```
#
# By default, the product launcher will search for a JDK to use, and if none
# can be found, it will ask for the location of a JDK and store its location
# in this file. If a particular JDK should be used instead, uncomment the
# line below and set the path to your preferred JDK.
#
SetJavaHome C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.7.0_03
```

**This setting overrides the setting in sqldeveloper.conf**

Comment: Thanks, was trying the above solution only to have it keep trying my old path. If you prefer to use the GUI to set this like on a clean install, just delete this line and it will prompt you to choose a JDK next time you start sqldeveloper.

Comment: Thanks, this helped me. I tried to set the path in the sqldeveloper installation directory, but it still pointed to the old jdk. Resetting file in my appdata directory made the trick. This is so annoying feature...

Comment: If you have a 64-bit version of SQL Developer, but for some reason your default JDK is a 32-bit JDK (e.g. if you develop an Eclipse RCP application which requires a 32-bit JDK), then you have to set the value of the SetJavaHome property in the product.conf file to a 64-bit version of JDK in order to run the SQL Developer. See my full answer for more information.

Answer (score 1):

The solution that worked for me:
If you have Sqldeveloper with java incorporated, you can use the \sqldeveloper\bin\sqldeveloper.bat to launch sqldeveloper as told [here](https://forums.oracle.com/thread/2323010?start=0&tstart=0).

Answer (score 1):

Version 1.5 is very, very old.

In the latest builds, we support 32 and 64 bit JDKs. In version 4.0, we find the JDK for you on Windows. If the software can't find it, it prompts for that path.

That path would look something like this
 C:\Java\jdk1.7.0_45

You can read more about this [here](http://www.thatjeffsmith.com/archive/2013/12/oracle-sql-developer-4-windows-and-the-jdk/).

Answer (score 1):

“C:\Users\admin\Downloads\sqldeveloper\sqldeveloper\bin\sqldeveloper.conf” is misleading, it’s not the file which sets the Java Home variable. The actually file used is”%AppData%\sqldeveloper{PRODUCT_VERSION}\product.conf” [in my case it is "%AppData%\sqldeveloper\1.0.0.0.0\product.conf"]

Answer (score 1):

The secret is you need to copy msvcr100.dll to the path where the installation says msvcr100.dll is missing  (dialog box) and then try to install the sql developer.

For me I had to create  bin folder in

**C:\sqldeveloper\jdk\bin**

and Copy **msvcr100.dll** to it.

If still not working! Try this!

You might also need to change the config file settings found in

**C:\sqldeveloper\sqldeveloper\bin**

Download and install 32 bit JDK (Windows) and set the path in config file as

SetJavaHome **C:/Program Files (x86)/Java/jdk1.7.0_01**

Answer (score 0):

There is another route of failure, besides the version of Java you are running: You could be running out of Heap/RAM

If you had a once working version of SQLDeveloper, and you are starting to see the screenshot referenced in the original post, then you can try to adjust the amount of space SQLDeveloper requests when starting up.

Edit the file:

/ide/bin/ide.conf

Edit the line that specifies the max ram to use: AddVMOption -Xmx, reducing the size. For example I changed my file to have the following lines, which solved the issue.

```
#AddVMOption  -Xmx640M   # Original Value
AddVMOption  -Xmx256M    # New Value
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have a **64-bit version of SQL Developer**, but for some reason your default JDK is a 32-bit JDK (e.g. if you develop an Eclipse RCP application which requires a 32-bit JDK), then you have to set the value of the `SetJavaHome` property in the `product.conf` file to a **64-bit version of JDK** in order to run the SQL Developer. 
For example:

```
SetJavaHome C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_80
```

The `product.conf` file is in my case located in the following directory:

```
C:\Users\username\AppData\Roaming\sqldeveloper\1.0.0.0.0
```

The solution described above worked in my case. The solutions of @evgenyl and @FGreg did not work in my case.

Answer (score 0):

The `Oracle SQL developer` is **not supported** by the `64bit JDK`. 
To resolve this issue:

1. Install a `32bit JDK (x86)`
2. Update your SQL developer config file (It should now point to the new `32bit JDK`).
3. Edit the `sqldeveloper.conf`, which can be found under `{ORACLE_HOME}\sqldeveloper\sqldeveloper\bin\sqldeveloper.conf`
4. Make sure `SetJavaHome` is pointing to your `32bit JDK`.

For example:

```
SetJavaHome C:\Program Files (x86) \Java\jdk1.6.0_13
```

Answer (score -1):

This is known to happen even if there are some syntactical errors in your heap space setting in the `sqldeveloper.conf`.
If you have defined the heap space in any of the wrong ways mentioned [here](http://javahowto.blogspot.in/2006/06/6-common-errors-in-setting-java-heap.html),
it still will show the same error when you launch it.

**EDIT :**
The correct way to set your heap size parameters would be something like this:

```
AddVMOption -XX:MaxPermSize=256M
AddVMOption -Xms256M
AddVMOption -Xmx768M
```

Answer (score -1):

I also had the same problem after installing 32 bit version of java  it solved.